# Animate SearchView in the toolbar

Tags: android, xml, search, whatsapp

Does anyone know if there is any Libary or something else which could help me to animate my searchView like in the WhatsApp Application?

When you press the search button of the toolsbar in the latest version of whatsapp you can see a white circle comming from the search icon and expanding to a search box with a white background.

Its kind of hard to describe.

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what this animation should look and work like. Not only are there people that do not use WhatsApp today, but WhatsApp may change their app in the future, altering or removing this animation.

Comment: You're right, I edited my Question @CommonsWare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look on github for a library called FabTransitionLayout, that's the one you're looking for.
Cheers

Comment: Thank you, thats the transition i was talking about. Now I just need to figure, out how to connect it with my searchView